# Unitary test PHP & Mocks

Tags: php, unit-testing

I am trying to code a test class but this is the first time I'm doing it, so I'm a little lost with the exemple I've got from class.

Here is my Exchange Class :

```
<?php 

//require 'User.php';
require 'Product.php';
require 'EmailSender.php';
require 'DatabaseConnection.php';

class Exchange{

private $dateDebut;
private $dateFin;
private $receiver;
private $product;
private $owner;
private $emailSender;
private $dbConnexion;

function __construct($dateDebut, $dateFin, $receiver, $product, $owner)
{
    $this->dateDebut = $dateDebut;
    $this->dateFin = $dateFin;
    $this->receiver = $receiver;
    $this->product = $product;
    $this->owner = $owner;
    $this->emailSender = new EmailSender();
    $this->dbConnexion = new DatabaseConnection();
}


public function save($dateDebut, $dateFin)
{

    if($this->owner->isValid()){
        $checkOwner = true;
    }

    if($this->receiver->isValid()){
        $checkReceiver = true;
    }

    if($this->product->isValid()){
        $checkProduct = true;
    }

    if(!empty($dateDebut) && $dateDebut > date("Y-m-d")){
        $checkDateDebut = true;
    }

    if(!empty($dateFin) && $dateFin > date("Y-m-d") && $dateFin > $dateDebut){
        $checkDateFin = true;
    }

    if($checkProduct == true && $checkReceiver == true && $checkOwner == true && $checkDateFin == true && $checkDateDebut == true){

            if($this->receiver->age < 19){
                $this->emailSender->sendMail($this->receiver->getEmail(), "Moins de 18 ans");
            }

            // enregistrer en base
            return 12;
    }
    else{
        return false;
    }

}


// Liste des setters

public function setDateDebut($dateDebut)
{
    $this->dateDebut = $dateDebut;
}

public function setDateFin($dateFin)
{
    $this->dateFin = $dateFin;
}

public function setReceiver($receiver)
{
    $this->receiver = $receiver;
}

public function setProduct($product)
{
    $this->product = $product;
}

public function setOwner($owner)
{
    $this->owner = $owner;
}

public function setEmailSender($emailSender)
{
    $this->emailSender = $emailSender;
}

public function setDBConnexion($dbConnexion)
{
    $this->dbConnexion = $dbConnexion;
}


// Liste des getters

public function getDateDebut()
{
    return $this->dateDebut;
}

public function getDateFin()
{
    return $this->dateFin;
}

public function getReceiver()
{
    return $this->receiver;
}

public function getProduct()
{
    return $this->product;
}

public function getOwner()
{
    return $this->owner;
}

public function getEmailSender()
{
    return $this->emailSender;
}

public function getDBConnexion()
{
    return $this->dbConnexion;
}

}

?>
```

And here is my "Test" class I tried to do.

```
<?php
```

require 'Exchange.php';

```
class ExchangeTest extends PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase{

    private $exchange;

    public function testSave()
    {
        $result = $this->exchange->save("2017-11-18", "2017-11-20");
        $this->assertEquals($result, 12);
    }
}
```

Any help with unitary test will be nice, thanks, I've got the error that the function data is null yet.

Comment: : "It looks like you're writing your own ORM. Have you considered using one that's already written, tested, and widely supported like [Doctrine](http://www.doctrine-project.org/), [Propel](http://propelorm.org/) or
[Eloquent](https://laravel.com/docs/master/eloquent)?"

Comment: Huh teacher told us that we had to do it from scratch

Comment: If it's an academic exercise that's fine, and using unit tests is absolutely the way to ensure you're doing it correctly, so good job there. I'm just concerned when people do this because they think it's necessary.

Comment: Well as I edited I've got an error that says "Fatal error: Call to a member function save() on null"

Comment: That means you didn't initialize the `$exchange` variable, so you can't use it until you do.

Comment: Where should I ? on the Test class or Exchange one

Comment: It's often best to initialize those inside of each test to avoid contaminating the results of one test with the mistakes made in another. Keep them as local variables.

Comment: Oh ok I think I've got in thanks bud

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you've defined a property which you haven't populated, so when you go to use it there's no object there to run methods on and it errors out.

In most unit test scenarios you want each test to be as self-contained as possible to avoid one test causing a cascade failure in another. Making this a local variable should fix the problem:

```
public function testSave()
{
  $exchange = new Exchange(...);

  $result = $this->exchange->save("2017-11-18", "2017-11-20");
  $this->assertEquals($result, 12);
}
```

You my want to create an `exchange()` factory method of some kind that properly initializes the `Exchange` instance to avoid having to repeat a lot of boilerplate inside of each test.

Comment: Last thing I forgot to mention, I need to create 3 objects respectively from classes User, Product and other User, in these classes I've got the function isValid that checks some parameters, how can I initialize them ? Via mocks ?

Comment: Since you're trying to test actual code, mocks aren't relevant here. Initialize them as you usually would, exercise them, verify with assertions.